E2E testing of a VS Code extension - failed to activate the extension
We are developing a VS Code extension and I am trying to create a Github action automation that will install VS Code, install the extension, and then run a few CLI command we have for the extension in order to validate regression.
I tried it both on Linux agent and a macOS agent, but in both of them I see that even though the extension is installed, it is not activated and I am not sure why.
My Github action workflow is something like this:
The workflow:
jobs:
  setup-vscode-and-repo:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Install VS Code
      run: |
        brew update
        brew install --cask visual-studio-code

    - name: Verify VS Code Installation
      run: | 
        /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code --version
    
    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '18'

    - name: Install additional dependencies
      run: npm install jsonwebtoken axios
  
        
    - name: Download Release Assets
      run: |
        if [ "${{ github.event.inputs.isQa }}" = "true" ]; then
          echo "Downloading QA release"
          gh release download v${{ github.event.inputs.tag }} --repo earlyai/vscode-extension --pattern "qa-EarlyAI-${{ github.event.inputs.tag }}.vsix"
        else
          echo "Downloading Prod release"
          gh release download v${{ github.event.inputs.tag }} --repo earlyai/vscode-extension --pattern "EarlyAI-${{ github.event.inputs.tag }}.vsix"
        fi

    - name: Install EarlyAI Extension
      run: |
        VSIX_FILE=$(ls *.vsix)
        echo "Installing $VSIX_FILE"
        code --install-extension $VSIX_FILE
        code --list-extensions

    - name: Verify Extension Installation
      run: |
        if code --list-extensions | grep -iq 'EarlyAI'; then
          echo "earlyAi extension is installed."
        else
          echo "earlyAi extension is not installed."
          exit 1
        fi
 
    - name: Clone Repository
      run: gh repo clone earlyai/${{ github.event.inputs.repository }}

    - name: Open VS Code on the cloned repository
      run: |
        code --disable-gpu ${{ github.event.inputs.repository }}
        cd ${{ github.event.inputs.repository }}
        touch early.log
        chmod 666 early.log
        echo "Code status after opening the repository"
        code --status

    - name: Wait for 10 seconds
      run: sleep 10

It seems like the VSC ode is up and the extension is installed but it was not activated. Looking for suggestions and what am I missing or an alternative approach to automate the installation and testing of VS Code extensions
